# Image grid using React and JSON?

Tags: list, reactjs, jsx

EDIT: I added this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/41899/).

I'm a noobie to JSX and I'm trying to (correctly) build an image grid in React using a JSON file of images.

What is the best or "correct" approach for doing this?

**My JSON file** (updated per Nick's suggestion):

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "./images/temp/playlist_tn_01.jpg",
      "className": "playlist-tn"
    },
    {
      "url": "./images/temp/playlist_tn_02.jpg",
      "className": "playlist-tn"
    },
    {
      "url": "./images/temp/playlist_tn_03.jpg",
      "className": "playlist-tn"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My List module (copied from an example online):**

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <li>{listValue}</li>;
           })}
        </ul>
      )
    }
  });

module.exports = List;
```

**My Updated list container component:**

```
var Playlist = React.createClass({
  render() {
    let playlistImages = $.getJSON('images/temp/playlist_tn.json', images);
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="pagefade" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
        <List list={playlistImages.images} />
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = Playlist;
```

[UPDATE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/41899/)

Comment: Your `List` component looks exactly correct, just show an image instead of an `li`. are you running into any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rendering the component like this, e.g. passing the `image` node to the `list` property:

```
var mainComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    let jsonFileData = //ajax call to get file here
    return (
      <List list={jsonFileData.images} />
    )
  }
})
```

Then your jsx should read like this, you need to map the properties of the json onto an `img` element, and you need to use `className` instead of `class` as the property name :

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.list.map(function(listValue){
            return <li><img url={listValue.url} className={listValue.class} /></li>;
           })}
        </ul>
      )
    }
  });

module.exports = List;
```

I would also recommend using arrow functions where possible in your maps, it makes things easier to read:

```
<ul>
  {this.props.list.map( image =>
    <li>
      <img url={image.url} className={image.class} />
    </li>
  )}
</ul>
```

If you change your json `class` property to be called `className` and `url` to be `src`, you could use the spread operator to set all the props in one go too:

```
<img {...image} />
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31gsfLkd/)

Comment: This is great, thank you. Yes, I meant to have className. I'm still fuzzy on where to place the actual ajax or getJSON call. I'm new to ajax too :) Assuming my json file path is images/temp/playlist_tn.json, where would I place the ajax block and what would it look like so it makes it into <List list={jsonFileData.images} /> ?

Comment: You need to read the file into `jsonFileData` before you pass it to the list, i will update the answer.

Comment: Check the top block of code that is now rendering `List`

Comment: I updated my list container component above (var Playlist). I was previously using const Playlist = () => ( ... because I'm still fuzzy on when to use const, var and let. I thought it was just an ES5 vs 6 thing but I think var lets you access the lifecycle. Anyway, I changed it to a var like your example.

Comment: You need to `JSON. Parse` the data from the file into the variable first

Comment: I added FIDDLE in my original post.

Comment: You don't have jquery referenced but you are using $.getJSON, which is also an async function so the list will render before it completes..

Comment: Thank you. I added jquery and moved the json call into a componentDidMount... but I'm just going to have to do some research over the weekend because I've dived too deep.

Comment: Ok, well i would appreciate the answer if it answers your original questionm which i think it does! You need to look into ES6, read more about JSON, it's very important in react as you are just modelling data, and data in javascript is basically JSON.

Comment: here, i fixed your fiddle and put it at the end of my answer too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111809/discussion-between-kirk-ross-and-nick-dewitt).